# Remove axis line from highchart graphic

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this graph. I have a grid and I want to insert in each row this graph.
The problem is that as you can see there is a small line in the left, it seems that this line is the graph axis. I need to remove it not only because of the visual aspect but because the axis increases the grid cell height.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    ​
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: null,
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar',
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            enabled: false,
            categories: [''],
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            enabled: false,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'';
            }
        },
        credits: 
        {
            enabled: false,
            position: 
            {
                align: 'left',
                x: 10
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [ {
            name: 'Clicks',
            data: [2]
        }, {
            name: 'Distributed Points',
            data: [3]
        }],
        exporting: 
        {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
});
​
```

​

Comment: have you tried setting the rendering property of the element to display:none; ?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you mean it by rendering property. But if I set display:none in the html i can hide the axis but the component height remains the same (the component height needs to be just the graph height).

Comment: Oh ok. Here is the JSFiddle I'm working with to look into the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/JEGGf/1/ SVG rendering... I'm not seeing any results yet playing around in the API http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart-object

Comment: Is the use of highcharts required for your solution?

Comment: It's not necessary, but I think it's a better solution than 'drawing' the bar by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

[Is this what you are after](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/JEGGf/2/)?
[image]

I set the xAxis `lineWidth: 0` and then after the plot is drawn:

```
$('.highcharts-axis').css('display','none');
```

EDIT:

If you also set `tickWidth: 0`, you can remove all traces of the axis lines without using the CSS call.

Revved fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JEGGf/4/).

Comment: I was hoping to give Thiago an answer built into the API. The problem with stylesheet overrides are that it is not guaranteed that the css hack will persist when the SVG updates. Also you find yourself on a slippery slope of making sure your wrapper correctly works with the 3rd party tool throughout the products life cycle.

Comment: As Christopher said, I was looking for a solution using the API.

Comment: But I have looked your example. Although the axis had disappear the 'svg' element keeps with the same height, in that case the highcharts increase the cell height also.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the cell height.  Regardless, if you also set the tickWidth:0, then you do not need the css hack to remove all traces of the axis lines.